# Why error "is not a valid resource reference. (Code:InvalidParameter)" is triggered when trying to create a VM via ARM-Template in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I receive the following error while trying to use the official MS ARM Template for VMs and cannot figure out why:

> New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : 7:40:25 AM - The deployment 'VM-ARM-Template' failed with error(s). Showing 1 out of 1 error(s).
> Status Message: Id /subscriptions/..../resourceGroups/testProdData/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/newTestVMNetInt is not a valid
> resource reference. (Code:InvalidParameter)

The template looks like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "vmName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "simpleLinuxVM",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of you Virtual Machine."
      }
    },
    "accounting": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "blabla",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Accounting information"
      }
    },
    "contact": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "use Full name e.g. ..."
      }
    },
    "status": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Test",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Test",
        "Prod"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "use Test or Prod"
      }
    },
    "adminUsername": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "myUserName",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Username for the Virtual Machine."
      }
    },
    "authenticationType": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "password",
      "allowedValues": [
        "sshPublicKey",
        "password"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Type of authentication to use on the Virtual Machine. SSH key is recommended."
      }
    },
    "adminPasswordOrKey": {
      "type": "securestring",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "SSH Key or password for the Virtual Machine. SSH key is recommended."
      }
    },
    "dnsLabelPrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[toLower(concat('simplelinuxvm-', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)))]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Unique DNS Name for the Public IP used to access the Virtual Machine."
      }
    },
    "ubuntuOSVersion": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "18.04-LTS",
      "allowedValues": [],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The Ubuntu version for the VM. This will pick a fully patched image of this given Ubuntu version."
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location for all resources."
      }
    },
    "VmSize": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Standard_D2s_v3",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The size of the VM"
      }
    },
    "virtualNetworkName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "vNet",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the VNET"
      }
    },
    "subnetName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Subnet",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the subnet in the virtual network"
      }
    },
    "networkSecurityGroupName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "SecGroupNet",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the Network Security Group"
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "publicIpAddressName": "[concat(parameters('vmName'), 'PublicIP' )]",
    "networkInterfaceName": "[concat(parameters('vmName'),'NetInt')]",
    "subnetRef": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('virtualNetworkName'), parameters('subnetName'))]",
    "osDiskType": "Standard_LRS",
    "subnetAddressPrefix": "10.1.0.0/24",
    "addressPrefix": "10.1.0.0/16",
    "linuxConfiguration": {
      "disablePasswordAuthentication": false
      // "ssh": {
      //   "publicKeys": [
      //     {
      //       "path": "[concat('/home/', parameters('adminUsername'), '/.ssh/authorized_keys')]",
      //       "keyData": "[parameters('adminPasswordOrKey')]"
      //     }
      //   ]
      // }
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
      "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
      "name": "[variables('networkInterfaceName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/', parameters('networkSecurityGroupName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses/', variables('publicIpAddressName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "ipConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "ipconfig1",
            "properties": {
              "subnet": {
                "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
              },
              "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
              "publicIpAddress": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses',variables('publicIPAddressName'))]"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "networkSecurityGroup": {
          "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups',parameters('networkSecurityGroupName'))]"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
      "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
      "name": "[parameters('networkSecurityGroupName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "securityRules": [
          {
            "name": "SSH",
            "properties": {
              "protocol": "TCP",
              "sourcePortRange": "*",
              "destinationPortRange": "22",
              "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
              "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
              "access": "Allow",
              "priority": 300,
              "direction": "Inbound",
              "sourcePortRanges": [],
              "destinationPortRanges": [],
              "sourceAddressPrefixes": [],
              "destinationAddressPrefixes": []
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "Port_1883",
            "properties": {
              "protocol": "*",
              "sourcePortRange": "*",
              "destinationPortRange": "1883",
              "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
              "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
              "access": "Allow",
              "priority": 310,
              "direction": "Inbound",
              "sourcePortRanges": [],
              "destinationPortRanges": [],
              "sourceAddressPrefixes": [],
              "destinationAddressPrefixes": []
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "Port_80",
            "properties": {
              "protocol": "*",
              "sourcePortRange": "*",
              "destinationPortRange": "80",
              "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
              "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
              "access": "Allow",
              "priority": 320,
              "direction": "Inbound",
              "sourcePortRanges": [],
              "destinationPortRanges": [],
              "sourceAddressPrefixes": [],
              "destinationAddressPrefixes": []
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "Port_8080",
            "properties": {
              "protocol": "*",
              "sourcePortRange": "*",
              "destinationPortRange": "443",
              "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
              "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
              "access": "Allow",
              "priority": 330,
              "direction": "Inbound",
              "sourcePortRanges": [],
              "destinationPortRanges": [],
              "sourceAddressPrefixes": [],
              "destinationAddressPrefixes": []
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "Port_8883",
            "properties": {
              "protocol": "*",
              "sourcePortRange": "*",
              "destinationPortRange": "8883",
              "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
              "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
              "access": "Allow",
              "priority": 340,
              "direction": "Inbound",
              "sourcePortRanges": [],
              "destinationPortRanges": [],
              "sourceAddressPrefixes": [],
              "destinationAddressPrefixes": []
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
      "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
      "name": "[parameters('virtualNetworkName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "tags": {
        "status": "[parameters('status')]",
        "accounting": "[parameters('accounting')]",
        "extint": "intern",
        "contact": "[parameters('contact')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "addressSpace": {
          "addressPrefixes": [
            "[variables('addressPrefix')]"
          ]
        },
        "subnets": [
          {
            "name": "[parameters('subnetName')]",
            "properties": {
              "addressPrefix": "[variables('subnetAddressPrefix')]",
              "privateEndpointNetworkPolicies": "Enabled",
              "privateLinkServiceNetworkPolicies": "Enabled"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses",
      "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
      "name": "[variables('publicIpAddressName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Basic",
        "tier": "Regional"
      },
      "properties": {
        "publicIpAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
        "publicIPAddressVersion": "IPv4",
        "dnsSettings": {
          "domainNameLabel": "[parameters('dnsLabelPrefix')]"
        },
        "idleTimeoutInMinutes": 4
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
      "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
      "name": "[parameters('vmName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "tags": {
        "status": "[parameters('status')]",
        "accounting": "[parameters('accounting')]",
        "extint": "intern",
        "contact": "[parameters('contact')]"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', variables('networkInterfaceName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "hardwareProfile": {
          "vmSize": "[parameters('VmSize')]"
        },
        "storageProfile": {
          "osDisk": {
            "createOption": "fromImage",
            "caching": "ReadWrite",
            "managedDisk": {
              "storageAccountType": "[variables('osDiskType')]",
              "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', variables('networkInterfaceName'))]"
            },
            "diskSizeGB": 30
          },
          "imageReference": {
            "publisher": "Canonical",
            "offer": "UbuntuServer",
            "sku": "[parameters('ubuntuOSVersion')]",
            "version": "latest"
          }
        },
        "networkProfile": {
          "networkInterfaces": [
            {
              "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', variables('networkInterfaceName'))]"
            }
          ]
        },
        "diagnosticsProfile": {
          "bootDiagnostics": {
            "enabled": true
          }
        },
        "osProfile": {
          "computerName": "[parameters('vmName')]",
          "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
          "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPasswordOrKey')]",
          "linuxConfiguration": "[if(equals(parameters('authenticationType'), 'password'), json('null'), variables('linuxConfiguration'))]"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "adminUsername": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[parameters('adminUsername')]"
    },
    "hostname": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[reference(variables('publicIPAddressName')).dnsSettings.fqdn]"
    },
    "sshCommand": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[concat('ssh ', parameters('adminUsername'), '@', reference(variables('publicIPAddressName')).dnsSettings.fqdn)]"
    }
  }
}
```

The powershell script is this:

```
New-AzResourceGroup -Name $rg2 -Location westeurope -Force
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment `
    -vmName 'newTestVM' `
    -ResourceGroupName $rg2 `
    -TemplateFile '.\VM-ARM-Template.json' `
    -contact 'blabla' `
    -status 'Test' `
    -adminUsername 'myUser' `
    -authenticationType 'password' `
    -adminPasswordOrKey ("adna234V0sad=sadklandv" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)
```

After running the script at least the supicious NetworkInterface is shown in the Azure portal and with the look into the json I get the same ID as given in the error description. I cannot explain why the is error is thrown anyway. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting your managed disk to a NIC.  You need to fix this ID to point to a managed disk.

```
        "managedDisk": {
          "storageAccountType": "[variables('osDiskType')]",
          "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', variables('networkInterfaceName'))]"
        },
```

Comment: Yes. Worked for me! Thanks. I wonder how that line was added. Probably it was the guy in front of the PC. How did you narrow down the error? By the error message it was not clear to me that this line causes the error.

Comment: To find this, I took the resource type that ARM was throwing the error for (networkInterfaces) and searched the template for everywhere that was being used in order to see something looked wrong (ie. incorrect format, template function syntax error, out of place, etc).

You may also want to check out Bicep (https://github.com/Azure/bicep).  It is a declarative scripting-like language used to build ARM deployments.  One of the goals is to make the syntax less verbose and more intuitive than JSON.